# Lighttpd Subdomains

Tags: subdomain, virtualhost, lighttpd

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
    server.document-root        = "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/development/api"
    server.errorlog         = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
    accesslog.filename          = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
}

$HTTP["host"] == "api.example.com" {
    server.document-root        = "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/development/api"
    server.errorlog         = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
    accesslog.filename          = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
}

$HTTP["host"] == "example.org" {
    server.document-root        = "/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/development/services"
    server.errorlog         = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
    accesslog.filename          = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
}
```

Above is an extract of my lighttpd.conf. example.com and example.org are working fine. Any idea why api.example.com refuses to work?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "refuses to work"?

Comment: Does not load, as if the domain didn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure "api.example.com" resolves to the IP of your server in DNS.

Comment: An A record, right?

Comment: Fantastic, you have saved my life of pain :)

Comment: You can either do an A record or a CNAME to the true dns name of the server. It's your choice.